# Is it possible to view log alerts in azure using azure powershell?

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring

I've tried to view log alerts in azure portal but can we view the log alerts using azure powershell or cli?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use [Azure Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/insights-powershell-samples) and [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/insights-cli-samples?toc=/azure/azure-monitor/toc.json) to view the log alerts

[`Get-AzureRmLog`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.insights/get-azurermlog?view=azurermps-6.10.0) PowerShell command gives you the detailed logs.

You can even also use [Log Analytics API](https://dev.loganalytics.io/) to view the logs

Comment: Can we filter the log alerts based on name and email associated with it??

Comment: I think you can filter that by passing the `-Detailedoutput` like [mentioned here](https://www.danielstocker.net/azure-governance-using-azure-logs-to-tie-resources-to-owners/) where you can filter whatever you would like